# Setting up Docker swarm standalone in no internet zone

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

While I am trying to run docker swarm standalone in the private network, but it(docker daemon) is always trying to connect to Internet.

I downloaded the swarm image and copied it to the host on which docker daemon is running and not connected to Internet. Tried to follow the documentation at https://store.docker.com/images/swarm. But getting the below error

**Command:** docker run swarm create

**Error:** 2018/10/17 07:29:22 Post https://discovery.hub.docker.com/v1/clusters: dial tcp: lookup discovery.hub.docker.com on 10.48.0.7:53: server misbehaving

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How did you copy the swarm image to a docker daemon host? Could you list it by `docker images`?

Comment: Do you really want to run the classic container based swarm, or did you intend to use swarm mode? Classic swarm has been superceded for most use cases.

Comment: @Light.G Yes after copying them I was able to see the swarm image in the host machine. I pulled the image to my local and did save+load to copy the image to the host

Comment: @BMitch I wanted to setup a Jenkins cluster and use the docket containers as slaves. So as I have multiple docker hosts I was trying to run them as docker swarm. I even tried with the swarm mode but got the similar error.

Comment: For your purposes, I'd just define multiple docker hosts for build agents than try to use classic swarm. If you install 18.09 (currently in RC), you can connect to remote hosts with ssh without the need to configure TLS.